# How to Access Protected Folder's in Cpanel

Tags: php, android, security, cpanel

I have a simple question, I have purchased a domain , I have created a folder on to it, and added few .php script files,
I am accessing those .php  files in android application using HTTP request.

Apparently all my script files are visible to every body, If i protect them from CPanel then how may i access then in android code?

Any body help.?

Comment: you have the difficult task of figuring out who is accessing your site from "android code" and who is not.

Comment: I have hosted my files to a IP address, there are few files which are seen in directory browsing, I wan tot hide those files, this is the point I wanted to ask, that my files do accessible to any device connected (php files) and no one can see the files by changing the directory name above.